# Jquery undefined variable when iterating

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple jquery HTML site which connects to a backend and should list an array. I've tried various ways to fix showing "undefined" when iterating through the objects and accessing their properties. I do not see anything obviously wrong in the debugger, the array seems to look just fine. There must be something essential I'm missing. What am I doing wrong?

This is the server's example response:

```
[
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "123",
  "description": "A long description",
  "image": ""
}
]
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSON Data Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>JSON Data Example</h1>

  <div id="data"></div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Make an AJAX request to the server
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:4711",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
        displayData(response);
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Error retrieving data from the server.");
        }
      });
    });

    function displayData(data) {
      var output = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var $obj = $(data[i]);
        output += "<div>";
        output += "<h2>ID: " + $obj.id + "</h2>";
        output += "<p>Name: " + $obj.name + "</p>";
        output += "<p>Description: " + $obj.description + "</p>";
        //output += "<img src='" + $obj.image + "' alt='Image'>";
        output += "</div>";
      }
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = output;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7vcu5hp3/

Example Debugger Info (just to show that the object exists but will be undefined when evaluated):

[image]

Comment: What is the intended purpose of this operation?: `var $obj = $(data[i]);`  Why not just refer to `data[i].id` and `data[i].name`, etc.?

Comment: That's what I had in first place. It doesn't make  difference.

Comment: It certainly could make a difference, as I wouldn't expect the jQuery object to have properties like `name` or `description`.  Can you update the question to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  You can replace the AJAX operation with hard-coded known data.

Comment: When I set hard coded data in the success function and pass it to displayData it just works as expected. What may be causing the difference in parsing the response?

Comment: We don't know what the response *is*.  Is `response` an array as you expect?  Is it an object?  Is it a string (which may or may not contain JSON data and need to be parsed as JSON)?  Your debugging would determine this.  The screen shot in the question doesn't match the code in the question, the answer below demonstrates a working example which you claim doesn't work, earlier you claimed that there's no difference between using the jQuery object or not, [but](https://jsfiddle.net/9s8z1ywc/) there [is](https://jsfiddle.net/9s8z1ywc/1/)... Everything here is very inconsistent and unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it helped me find the actual issue: The backend simply provided wrong data, wrapping the response in another array. So there was an ill single item array wherein the actual response array with the expected data was wrapped. I overlooked that, it is not what is expected from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to convert it to a jquery object (which there is no reason for in this case), you will need to add [0] to **$(data[i])** so its **$(data[i])[0]**.

Since you are using jQuery you can easily loop through arrays with **$.each**. you don't need a for loop

```js
let data = [{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "123",
  "description": "A long description",
  "image": ""
}]

function displayData(data) {
  var output = "";
  $.each(data,function(k,obj){
    output += "<div>";
    output += "<h2>ID: " + obj.id + "</h2>";
    output += "<p>Name: " + obj.name + "</p>";
    output += "<p>Description: " + obj.description + "</p>";
    //output += "<img src='" + $obj.image + "' alt='Image'>";
    output += "</div>";
  })
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = output;
}

displayData(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried it this way as well. Your code still shows "undefined" for each property, whereas I can see the object just fine in the debugger like {"id": ...}.